# WSO2 Governance Registry import other schema within a schema

Tags: xsd, wso2

I'm trying to import schema files in the WSO2 Governance Registry (4.6.0) which include an import to other xsd's. The import happens using the include element.
Eg:

```
<xs:include schemaLocation="OtherSchemaToImport.xsd"/>
```

When uploading the XSD I receive following error:

```
Unable to upload file File upload failed. Failed to add resource
/_system/governance/myXsd.xsd.
Could not read the XML Schema Definition file. this.schema.needs
```

When removing the include, and specifying all elements in one XSD, the problem disappears, this is however not an acceptable solution.
Could you please give me some advice, things to try or a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can overcome this when you upload all [resources as *.gar file](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance460/Uploading+Schemas+with+Imports+from+Local+Filesystem+into+Governance+Registry). Where, you have to edit import definition with the location where you keep the imported resources and make a archive file and upload.

Comment: Thank you, this is indeed working, however it's not very flexible.
My xsd's extend from eachother to support versioning. I have several xsd types, and several versions of each xsd. V3.0 includes V2.0 which includes V1.0 which includes a 'common.xsd'. I did some tests and it seems I can't simply add a new version to the registry, eg: V4.0.
To upload V4.0 I first must remove all other versions and reupload them.
Because I need these XSD's to validate messages, it seems I will have downtime on my service. Is there any way to avoid doing that?